App.jsx does not render imported JSX components -> shows blank page in browser
I'm trying to switch my static website to React. I've never used React before so I'm clueless to what the error could be.
My current App.jsx looks like the following:
import React from "react";

import Header from './components/Header.jsx';
import Home from './components/Home.jsx';
import About from './components/About.jsx';
import Contact from './components/Contact.jsx';
import Footer from './components/Footer.jsx';
import styles from './App.module.css';

function App() {
    return (
        <div className={styles}>
            <Header />
            <main>
                <Home />
                <About />
                <Contact />
            </main>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;


The other JSX Components all follow the same structure (e.g. About.jsx):
import React from "react";

import WorkExperience from './WorkExperience.jsx';

function About() {
    return (
        <section id="about">
            <h1 className="about-main">I&aposm a <span className="highlight">{`{Software Developer}`}</span></h1>
            <p className="about-current-situation">Currently, I&aposm studying at BZWU in Wil, St. Gallen, Switzerland,</p>
            <p className="about-self-taught">A self-taught Java and C# developer, working in this industry for 2 years now. My goal is to deliver solutions to customers which fit their needs and goals.</p>

            <h2 className="work-experience-header">Work Experience</h2>
            <div className="work-experience-container">
                <WorkExperience />
            </div>

            <div className="currently-looking">
                <p className="currently-looking-big">I&aposm currently looking to join a <span className="highlight2">cross-functional</span> team</p>
                <p className="currently-looking-small">that values improving people&aposs lives through high quality software</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
}

export default About;


I tested it with a test App.jsx provided by Copilot:
import React from 'react';

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>App is rendering correctly</h1>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong or what I'm missing?
I'd appreciate it if anyone can help me in this matter and give me some advice on how to solve problems like these on my own.
I tried googling, React Docs and Copilot. I'm not getting any warnings nor errors.
The Website only shows a blank page when inserting my App.jsx. The main.jsx and the index.html function correctly when using the test app.jsx

What does your main.jsx look like?

First thing to do when you get a blank page is check your browser dev-tools Console for errors

Could be an import resolution bug. You typically don't need or want to include the .jsx extension in your import paths

@gaitat
`
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App.jsx';
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render();
`
I got it to work, the error was with a problem of displaying my SVG files
